# Delete all array index elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, delete-file, array-splice

I have a button that sends the index of an image to a javascript function.
It's a simple foreach loop that loops image rows in database.

`rImagem()` receives as argument the index that I need to erase inside array `imagens`.

**PHP script:**

```
<php foreach((array)$images_gallery as $key => $value): ?>
   if($value != null):
   <a href="#" onclick="rImagem('<?php echo $key;?>');return false;">Send</a>
<php endif;
endforeach;
?>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function rImagem(data){
    data = data -1;
    var parse_obj = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('imagens').value);
    parse_obj.splice(data,1);
    console.log(parse_obj);
    new_string = JSON.stringify(parse_obj);
    document.getElementById('imagens').value = new_string;
    //console.log(Object.keys(document.getElementsByClassName("btn_remover")));
    var i = 1;
    if(document.getElementsByClassName("btn_remover").length == i){
    }
    else{
        document.getElementsByClassName("btn_remover")[data].remove();
    }
}
```

The problem is array images is not well erased. I could never erase only one element left in the array (index = 0). And I need to be able to do it.

Another problem is that sometimes I click an element to delete and it deletes the next index in the array, instead of the clicked element index.

`splice` method reindexes the array, `delete` method maintains the array immutable. But none of this has worked so far.

With `btn_remover` I also try to remove the correct image thumbnail when I click in it.

Any ideas to fix this issue?

Comment: The indices of parse_obj will shift each time you remove an element, so this won't work.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Removing elements from an array, by pressing a button that is a thumbnail of the image. Also when pressing the button the button also dissapears.

Comment: I don't understand why `delete` won't work for this case? Can you explain why?

Comment: With delete it leaves gaps in the array , and i need to have the array contiguous.

Comment: @AndréCastro " I want it contiguous with deletes, but I don't want it re-indexed". How are your requirements possible?

Comment: Yes... its a contradition... but i need to delete the array not leaving visible gaps and maintaining the index numbering. Like this: [1,3,7], not like [,1, ,3,7].

Comment: I don't think you do need worry about array indices at all, I think there is probably a much simpler way to solve the problem.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: @AndréCastro I understand what you're asking, but it's simply not possible because you are wanting to rely on the index of the array to match the value. You can achieve exactly what you just described with `splice()`, but then your indexes don't match up

Comment: @AndréCastro James is right that relying on the index is the wrong way to go (as I described in my comment above). Can you edit your question to describe the problem you are trying to solve, rather than asking about your attempted solution?

Comment: Yes... maybee i need to write another aproach without the foreach loop to pass Keys as indexes... I think the problem it there...

Comment: @AndréCastro I have a feeling it will have to do with whatever your `imagens` value looks like. Including that piece is extremely relevant in the answering of your question.